# apache2 with access_compat module

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, access-denied, opensuse

I should continue work on one exists project and try to run environment on my local machine.

It is opensuse with apache 2.4.29 with php55/php70. I have issue with access in combination with `access_compat` module.

My virtualhost config file is:

```
<VirtualHost dev.bona.eu:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/vhosts/bona/httpdocs
    ServerName dev.bona.eu
    ServerAdmin admin@bona.eu
    <Directory /srv/www/vhosts/bona/httpdocs>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /srv/www/vhosts/bona/log/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/vhosts/bona/log/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

But project have old logic in `.htaccess` file like:

```
<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

It is reason why I enabled `access_compat` module.

Without `access_compat` module I get error:

`.htaccess: Invalid command 'order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

But with `access_compat` module error is:

`[access_compat:error] [pid 16824] [client 192.168.0.106:39628] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /srv/www/vhosts/bona/httpdocs/index.php`

List of all loaded modules is:

```
LoadModule authz_host_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule actions_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_alias.so
LoadModule authz_user_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_file_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule cgi_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_env.so
LoadModule expires_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_expires.so
LoadModule include_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule setenvif_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule userdir_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_headers.so
LoadModule status_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule authz_core_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authn_core_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule version_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_version.so
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_php5.so
```

Any hint here, please?

Comment: What else does the .htaccess file (or files?) contain?

Comment: For this project is so long, but I tried this with Laravel project too, but trick is change in virtualhost file to old configuration (with Order).